# Button needs to be disapear and come back

Tags: swift

I've got now an app that if you click on a button it will disappear, now I want to make the button disappear even when your not clicking on that button, but it will come back in a few seconds (or even less than a second). On the moment this is how the button looks in the code.

```
    @IBAction func increaseCount(button: UIButton) -> Void {
    button.hidden = true
    ourScore.text = "\(++score)"


    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(Double((arc4random_uniform(1) + 2)) * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        button.hidden = false
    }
}
```

How is it possible to make the button disappear even when your not clicking it, but it will come back in just a few seconds (and less than a second) back? The time should be random between 2 and a half second. When your clicking it should also disappear and it will come back less than 2 seconds.

Who could help me?

Comment: have you tried `UIView` animations?

Comment: I've searched on UIView animations but didn't know how to search it specific.

Comment: So what is the trigger 'when your not clicking on that button' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will have the button appear and reappear on its own every 2 seconds. You can modify the time so it is random (if you need help with that, let me know).

Link your button on the story board and the code below should do the trick.

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button.hidden = true
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: "appear:", userInfo: self, repeats: false)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func appear(timer: NSTimer) {
    self.button.hidden = true
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: "disappear:", userInfo: self, repeats: false)

}

func disappear(timer: NSTimer) {
    self.button.hidden = false
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: "appear:", userInfo: self, repeats: false)

}
```

EDIT: For the button to disappear when clicked, register an Action event from the button and use the code:

```
@IBAction func clicked(sender: UIButton) {
    self.button.hidden = true
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "appear:", userInfo: self, repeats: false)
}
```

Again, this hides it just for 1 second when it is clicked, but you can change the time to be random.

Edit 2: You should see this:

[image: Storyboard Connections]

Comment: Thank you for your help there are just a few problems, The button should be first on the screen, when I start the app the button it isn't there until a few seconds. It worked with disappearing and coming back only it didn't start. The next thing is when I click on the button it should disappear but when I do the button freezes and went back to Xcode to Thread 1 > 12 main > 'class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {' (AppDelegate) marked green with "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT. I hope you can help

Comment: Okay for the button to initially be on the screen just change button.hidden = true to button.hidden = false in the viewDidLoad(). And to make the button disappear when it is clicked, you should add a Touch Up Inside Event from the button and use an NSTimer within it. I will update the code above to include this. Also make sure that you check your Storyboard and have only the current connections used in your code associated with the button.

Comment: The button will be on the screen when I start the app, thanks for that. But by when I click I will get the same message. I've done this: I did connect the same button to the code with an action, Touch Up inside Event and written the rest of the code. By the storyboard the connection of the button  are by Sent Events: Touch up inside -> view controller clicked (Black dot) view controller button (not black dot/no dot) and by Referencing Outlets: button -> view controller (black dot). Hope you can see the mistake and can help.

Comment: The code works for me so I can't really pinpoint anything. I am going to upload a screenshot of the StoryBoard connections so you can just double check; check my newest edit. Otherwise, I am not sure, sorry. I can upload the app on github for you if it comes to that.

Comment: I did delete a connection, that wasn't necessary. But it didn't work. Could you give your project? Thanks.

Comment: It worked. I didn't found a mistake at my code but I compared it with your code and it worked. Thank you so much. Have a nice day!

Comment: Don't forget to select the checkmark if you think this is the solution! And no problem!